# Reliable peak picking algorithm?

Tags: autocorrelation, peak-detection, soft-question

I've written an application that estimates pitch based on autocorrelation function. I did peak picking by comparing vector values to determine whether the central one is a peak or not, but this method is not working well.

Can someone indicate a reliable peak picking algorithm?

Comment: i have little idea what you mean by "comparing vector values to determine whether the central one is a peak or not..."  what vector?  (how'zit defined?)  and "central one"?  "one" what?  and can you use a little $\LaTeX$ and show us how you are defining your autocorrelation function in terms of the samples?

Comment: you might want to take a look at [this paper](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/tartini/papers/A_Smarter_Way_to_Find_Pitch.pdf).